# Is there an event function in Angular that is executed after `ngOnChanges`?

Tags: angular

I use Angular and use a template to render a list of items by using `*ngFor`. Each item in the list has an `img` tag and I load only the images of the items that are visible in the viewport.

That means, I have 2 events here where this is checked. In `ngAfterViewInit` (for the first draw) and in the mouse wheel event. Example:

```js
@HostListener("mousewheel")
scroll(event: MouseEvent) {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.load_Images_Visible_In_The_Viewport();
    }, 250);
}
```

If the parent component updates the list (which is an `@Input`) I can't trigger the function `load_Images_Visible_In_The_Viewport` because where can I do that? `ngOnChanges` is too soon before `*ngFor` is executed.

I am looking for a function like: `ngUpdateViewAfterChanges`. Does something like this exist in Angular? Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: No shortage of docs on the lifecycle hooks in angular: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: I found this article already. Does that mean there is no solution to this problem?

Comment: If you're using input properties, then `ngOnChanges` would seem to be the lifecycle to go with. If it happens too soon, then maybe you need to check the proper [`SimpleChange`](https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChange) that is passed into `ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges)` to see if the change is the first change (`isFirstChange()`), and ignore that one.

Comment: Thanks! So I understand correctly SimpleChanges is executed after `*ngFor` is executed and the elements are created and displayed in the viewport?

Comment: `SimpleChanges` isn’t executed. It is a parameter that gets passed into `ngOnChanges`. It is available every time an `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook fires. You can evaluate the contents of that, and act accordingly. See [this](https://medium.com/@sithummeegahapola/what-is-angular-simplechanges-in-ngonchange-method-2e6b8e7f411d).

Comment: Thank you! I could accept that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `@Input` properties, then `ngOnChanges` would be the lifecycle to go with.

If it happens too soon, then maybe you need to check the proper [`SimpleChange`](https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChange) that is passed into `ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges)` to see if the change is the first change (`isFirstChange()`), and ignore that one.

[SimpleChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChanges) is a parameter that gets passed into `ngOnChanges`. It is available every time an `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook fires. You can evaluate the contents of that, and act accordingly.

From the Angular docs cited below:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    for (const propName in changes) {
        const chng = changes[propName];
        const cur  = JSON.stringify(chng.currentValue);
        const prev = JSON.stringify(chng.previousValue);
        this.changeLog.push(`${propName}: currentValue = ${cur}, previousValue = ${prev}`);
    }
}
```

References:

- https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#using-change-detection-hooks
- https://medium.com/@sithummeegahapola/what-is-angular-simplechanges-in-ngonchange-method-2e6b8e7f411d

Comment: I tried this, and it kind of works, but `ngOnChanges` is executed before `*ngFor` is updated and therefore I can't update any DOM elements yet